# Error when changing the value of an object within an array causing another object to be called

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a project where I need the values in an array to change depending on if a button is clicked for that specific item. Right now, I'm able to get the first `name` (pescatarian) in my first `subCategories` object to work, but when I press the second one (vegan), it is displaying my second `subCategories` object and changing `data[0]` to

```
"category": "Diet", "subCategories": [{"name": "one", "value": false}, {"name":"two", "value": false}, {"name": "three", "value": false}, {"name": "four", "value": false}]}
```

from:

```
{"category": "Diet", "subCategories": [{"name": "pescatarian", "value": false}, {"name": "vegan", "value": false}, {"name": "vegetarian", "value": false}]}
```

From there, I am able to press the first two `subCategories` (one and two), but if I press the third one I get an error stating: `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data[index].subCategories')`. Does anyone know why this is happening? I would really appreciate any help or advice. Thank you!

```
const [data, setData] = useState([
     {
        category: 'Diet',
        subCategories: [
          {name:'pescatarian', value: false }, 
          {name:'vegan', value: false }, 
          {name:'vegetarian', value: false }
        ],
     }, {
        category: 'Daily Exercise in Hours',
        subCategories: [
          {name:'one', value: false },
          {name:'two', value: false }, 
          {name:'three', value: false }, 
          {name:'four', value: false }
        ],
      },
  ])
```

```
const onChangeValue = (item, index, newValue) => {
    console.log('data[index]:', data[index].subCategories)
    const newSub = data[index].subCategories.map(subCat => {
      if (subCat.name.includes(item.name)) {
        return {
          ...subCat,
          value: newValue,
        }
       }
      return subCat
    })
    const newData = data.map(newItem => {
      if (newItem.subCategories.some(x => x.name === item.name)){
        return {
          ...newItem,
          subCategories:newSub,
        }
      }
      return newItem
    })
    setData(newData)
  }
```

```
onValueChange={newValue => onChangeValue(item, index, newValue)}
```

Comment: There is not value at index `2` of the state array ....

Comment: It isn't clear how `index` is assigned within your JSX code, but it is somehow out of bounds of your `data` array. You're probably trying to access an item at index `2` when the length of the array is 2, for example.

Comment: Ya, thank you, I just realize that from your comments that my indexes are coming from within```subCategories``` not my ```data``` array in general.